# In Laravel How to add multiple value of dropdown as an object in a single database cell

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

This is a dropdown with multiple values:

```
<select multiple size="4" name="darha[]">
@foreach($doors as $door)
<option value="{ image: '{{ $door->image }}'; code: '{{ $door->code }}'}"{{ $door->code }}</option>
 @endforeach
</select>
```

And this is my controller in store function as:

```
$product->darha = implode(', ', $request->darha);
```

The inserted data in table is like:

```
{ image: '1527585419301-Door-T-D.jpg'; code: '301-Door-T-D' }, { image: '1527851661402-Door-A-T.jpg'; code: '402-Door-A-T' }
```

and here is the question how can I access each object value or property. I mean, how can I access to image or code value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json format is not valid.

There are three issues with your json format:

1) If you want to have array of objects, you need to wrap them in brackets `[]`

2) Your json keys and values must be in double quotes not single!

3) Separator between keys must be `,` not `;`

---

So try to embed your json string like so:

```
<option value='{"image":"{{ $door->image }}", "code": "{{ $door->code }}"}'>{{ $door->code }}</option>
```

If you have a json string like this:

```
$var = '[{ "image": "1527585419301-Door-T-D.jpg", "code": "301-Door-T-D" },{ "image": "1527851661402-Door-A-T.jpg", "code": "402-Door-A-T" }]';
```

You can convert that to a json object as below:

```
$myObjects = json_decode($var);
```

and then access each key like so:

```
$myObjects[0]->image; //'1527585419301-Door-T-D.jpg'
```

**UPDATE**

If you are sending a json string from Laravel to javascript, it will automatically convert to a json object.

Assume you return below json string from Laravel to js:

```
$var = '{"image": "1527585419301-Door-T-D.jpg", "code": "301-Door-T-D" }';
return $var;
```

In js side you can reach properties like this:

```
var $darha = data.image; // '1527585419301-Door-T-D.jpg'
```

Comment: great answer. I want to get data and show them by ajax. As you said I corrected the format and I get the data and store it in : var $darha = data.darha and console.log() show it correctly. And the question is how I show each property and value? do I must var $darha = data.darha.splite(', ') or JSON.stringfy($darha) or .... please guide me. tkx

Comment: @MehdiYaghoubi See UPDATE